# routing legacy webforms urls to mvc controller/actions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

We are planning to convert legacy webforms incrementally over to MVC. (and learning MVC along the way!)

I am wondering if routing is the appropriate way to, ineffect, replace old webforms pages with controllers/actions one at a time.  Right now we have this which was generated for us when creating the MVC area and adding MVC to the project with nuget:

```
Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As AreaRegistrationContext)
    context.MapRoute(
        "MVC_default",
        "MVC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

So controller "foo" with action "bar", is reference with url ".../AppName/MVC/foo/bar", while aspx pages are accessed with urls in ".../AppName/Pages/PageName".

Can I use additional MapRoute() calls above, or maybe MapPageRoute() to in a RouteConfig.vb in App_Start, to specifically map individual pages to the corresponding new MVC controller/action?  What would that look like?

This would let us avoid touching the messy code-behind on the webforms side for constructing our navigation urls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, you can have MVC routes masquerade as WebForms or Classic ASP URLs using [IIS Rewrite rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).  You don't have to change any legacy links that may be floating out there, and you can keep the old WebForms pages around, and switch between MVC/WebForms/Classic ASP (without redeploying the site) by toggling the rewrite rules.

You can choose between a redirect or a rewrite, depending on whether or not you want the client to see the new MVC URL.

Here's an example of a Classic ASP -> MVC rewrite rule in a web.config:

```
<rule name="AppPageRewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="app.asp" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/app" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

By the way, converting a Web Forms/Classic ASP site incrementally to MVC  (on a per page, or even sub-page level) has proven very effective in my experience (works especially well in an Agile/Scrum environment).